# Converting tree insertion to iterative function

Tags: java, recursion, red-black-tree

My question is how can I convert this function pair into a single non recursive call? As I understand any recursive call may be turned into an iterative algorithm yielding the same result.

```
public void insert(Key key, Value value){
       root = insert(root, key, value);
       root.color = BLACK;
}
private Node insert(Node h, Key key, Value value) {

       /*1*/ if (h == null)      return new Node(key, value);

       /*2*/ if (isRed(h.left) && isRed(h.right)) colorFlip(h);

       /*3*/ int cmp = key.compareTo(h.key);
       /*4*/ if (cmp == 0) h.val = value;
       /*5*/ else if (cmp < 0) h.left = insert(h.left, key, value); 
       /*6*/ else              h.right = insert(h.right, key, value);

       /*7*/ if (isRed(h.right) && !isRed(h.left))     h = rotateLeft(h);
       /*8*/ if (isRed(h.left)  && isRed(h.left.left)) h = rotateRight(h);
             return h; 
  }
```

I see that line 2 evaluates the node as it's pushed into the stack.   I also notice that a node is pushed onto a user defined stack in lines 5 and 6. My confusion starts when I start thinking about where lines 7 and 8 would occur, and how to pop off the nodes and correctly link them to the left or right pointers.

Comment: It may help to break it into two recursive function first. One to insert and the other to balance. I think you may get two tail recursive function which are easy to convert.

Comment: Thats an interesting way to look at it. I'll see if that approach will help solve it.

Answer (score 0):

My intution would be that doing so "should" produce some cludgy mess like this...

```
public void insert(Key key, Value value) {

Stack<Node> nodeStack = new Stack<>();
Stack<Key> keyStack = new Stack<>();
Stack<Value> valStack = new Stack<>();

nodeStack.push(root);
keyStack.push(key);
valStack.push(value);

boolean done = false;

while(!done) {
   //here you cut-past the 3-parameter insert method...
   //BUT...
   //replace all uses have h, key, and value with stack.peek() calls
   //push new items to each stack everytime you call insert(Node n, Key k, Value v) (and do a continue)
   //pop items from each stack each time you leave insert
   //set done to true when the recurssion should end

         //you also MAY need some a Node var to hold the last returned value
}

 root.color = BLACK;
}
```

Moral of the story is...you need to replace the software stack with a few stacks of your own.  The outline above may not be perfect, but its a start.

Out of curiosity, what makes you ask?

Comment: What sparked this was I have other more complicated recursive functions that I would like to benchark against their iterative counterparts. Figured I would start small.